# Cannot setup sticky-footer properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs, sticky-footer

I am learning web development from a course on Udemy and I ran into a problem. I cannot seem to get the footer to behave the way I want it. The thing is that when there is more data, the footer starts overlapping on it, as I have put the position:relative for it in CSS. But if I remove that, if the page is not completely filled (e.g. Login page), the footer does not stay at the bottom of the page, instead jumps up to the lowest parts of the Login form.

I am seeking advice/help on how to make the footer stick to the bottom of the page and for it to stay there and get pushed in case the page fills up with data and reaches the edges of the footer.
Note: I am using EJS for this and have header and footer partials.

The Login form HTML:

```html
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST">
            <h1 class="mb-3 text-center">Please sign in</h1>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required
                autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                required>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <a href="/forgot" id="forgotPassword">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
        <div class="form-signin">
            <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

The header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Yelp Camp</title>
    <meta name="viewwport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.2.1/united/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-udHIRBY7G8ZUr7aO8wRn7wD4bsGGRLR5orCz1FV93MZ7232xhAdjDYEvqeZLx45b" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary mb-2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">YelpCamp</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'campgrounds' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <% if(!currentUser){ %>
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'login' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'register' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <% } else { %>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Signed in as
                        <%= currentUser.username %></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div>
        <% if (error && error.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <%= error %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if (success && success.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <%= success %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-content">
```

The footer:

```html
</div> <!-- /.page-content -->
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">
            &copy; YelpCamp 2018 | <a href="/campgrounds">Home</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The relevant CSS:

```css
.form-signin {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page-content {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 0 -60px !important;
    position: relative;
}

footer .footer-push{
    height: 60px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    clear: both;
}

.container .text-muted{
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
```

I have tried a good dozen different attempts for sticky-footers, but none of them worked so far. The main problems were:

- The page with almost no data (e.g. Login page) had the footer below the bounds of the screen (scroll needed to see it) or right after the login form (not at the bottom of the page where I would like to have it);
- The page with enough data to fill the page had the footer overlapping the data in the middle of the page (even before scrolling).

Current problems:

- [The footer in the login page is not staying at the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHQu4.png)
- [Even though the footer's height is set to 60px, it just shrinks to around 19 (zoomed out view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTCMd.png)

[Codepen link for the Login Page example of the code.](https://codepen.io/Precigus/pen/NeyOdv) (Note: The problem is visible only in Full view)

I would be really grateful if anyone could assist me in finding a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or codepen demo?

Comment: Your snippet is not working, please edit and to run

Comment: So far I am doing it on VSCode. But I will try to setup a codepen demo for this, if it works there the same way.

Comment: @Justcode Sorry, the snippet was the only way I could insert the code from ejs here, it didn't work if I used the other methods.
I am a beginner at this and not really sure how to change it from ejs at this point to make it run in the snippets. I will try to post screenshots of the problems I am facing

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining that the footer must be hugging the bottom of the screen.  Try adding this.

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you run into an issue with the other content now being covered by the footer, just add some margin/padding at the bottom of the last div that is of equal height to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` to define the sticky position and set `bottom:0` to define the location where you want it to be.

Try this

```css
.form-signin {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page-content {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 0 -60px !important;
    position: relative;
}

footer .footer-push{
    height: 60px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    clear: both;
}

.container .text-muted{
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}

footer {position: fixed; bottom:0; text-align:center; width:100%; background:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST">
            <h1 class="mb-3 text-center">Please sign in</h1>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required
                autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                required>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <a href="/forgot" id="forgotPassword">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
        <div class="form-signin">
            <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Yelp Camp</title>
    <meta name="viewwport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.2.1/united/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-udHIRBY7G8ZUr7aO8wRn7wD4bsGGRLR5orCz1FV93MZ7232xhAdjDYEvqeZLx45b" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary mb-2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">YelpCamp</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'campgrounds' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <% if(!currentUser){ %>
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'login' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item <%= typeof page !== 'undefined' && page === 'register' ? 'active' : '' %>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <% } else { %>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Signed in as
                        <%= currentUser.username %></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div>
        <% if (error && error.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <%= error %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if (success && success.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <%= success %>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-content">
          </div> <!-- /.page-content -->
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container"> 
        <p class="text-muted">
            &copy; YelpCamp 2018 | <a href="/campgrounds">Home</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
The thing is, that if I use posigion:fixed, the footer is always visible on the page. I want it to stay at the bottom after the content, and at the bottom even if there isn't enough content to fill the whole page in question. 
Another thing I cannot figure out is why my footer shrunk. It's set to 60px height, but it shows up as about 19px.

Comment: Then you have to set margin to separate the content from the footer

Comment: But if I set a fixed margin size, then if the page has more content than fits the view and I have to scroll down, there will be a gap of that size between the end of the content and the footer. That doesn't seem like a fluid design that would fit all screen sizes.

Comment: Then setting the height will be the only option